# Trying to re-create a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the following image, I have started it but its not how I expect.

[image]

I would like the option to add colours to the network also - like:

[image]

How can I add these changes? If I can just finish the one model, I think I will be able to finish the second one.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    embedding/.style={rectangle,draw=black,text centered},
    index/.style={circle,draw=black,text centered, minimum width=0.45cm},
    hidden/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,rectangle split parts=7,draw=black},
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] 
\node[embedding] (Wt) {$w_t$};
\node[hidden] (h1)[above=of Wt]{} edge [<-] (Wt);
\node[index] (W-2) [above left =of h1] {$w_{t-2}$} edge [<-] (h1);
\node[index] (W-1) [right =of W-2] {$w_{t-1}$}edge [<-] (h1);
%\node[index] (W0) [right =of W-0] {$w_{t0}$}edge [<-] (h1) ; % add in a w_0 here and colour it differently to the other nodes at this line
\node[index] (W+1) [right =of W-1] {$w_{t+1}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\node[index] (W+2) [right =of W+1] {$w_{t+2}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The commented out line of code in your MWE somehow does not fit to the first image in your question as there is no w_{t0} in the image. Guessing from the commented out line, is the following closer to what you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPs2R.png

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have slightly changed the order in which the round nodes are drawn. I have placed W0 directly above of h1 and then worked my way to the left and right (using `left=of...` and `right=of...` respectively). In order to color the W0 node, I have added `fill=yellow`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    embedding/.style={rectangle,draw=black,text centered},
    index/.style={circle,draw=black,text centered, minimum width=0.45cm},
    hidden/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,rectangle split parts=7,draw=black},
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] 
\node[embedding] (Wt) {$w_t$};
\node[hidden] (h1)[above=of Wt]{} edge [<-] (Wt);
\node[index] (W0) [above =of h1, fill=yellow] {$w_{t0}$}edge [<-] (h1) ; % add in a w_0 here and colour it differently to the other nodes at this line
\node[index] (W-1) [left =of W0] {$w_{t-1}$}edge [<-] (h1);
\node[index] (W-2) [left =of W-1] {$w_{t-2}$} edge [<-] (h1);
\node[index] (W+1) [right =of W0] {$w_{t+1}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\node[index] (W+2) [right =of W+1] {$w_{t+2}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer all of your circular nodes to have the same radius, you can use a larger `minimum` width as follows: `index/.style={circle,draw=black,text centered, minimum width=1.2cm},`

[image]

---

To make the Wt box circular as well, replace `\node[embedding] (Wt) {$w_t$};` with `\node[index] (Wt) {$w_t$};`:

[image]

---

To replace the seven boxes with a single circle of the same radius as the others, you can replace `\node[hidden] (h1)[above=of Wt]{} edge [<-] (Wt);` with `\node[index] (h1)[above=of Wt]{} edge [<-] (Wt);`:

[image]

---

If you want to individually change the radius of a single circle, you can use `minimum width` as in `\node[index] (h1)[above=of Wt, minimum width=0.5cm]{} edge [<-] (Wt);`:

[image]

---

To remove W0 and keep a white space where it was, you can use the following code with `above left= of h1` and `above right= of h1` for W-1 and W+1 respectively:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    index/.style={circle,draw=black,text centered, minimum width=0.45cm},
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] 
\node[index] (Wt) {$w_t$};
\node[index] (h1)[above=of Wt]{} edge [<-] (Wt);
\node[index] (W-1) [above left =of h1] {$w_{t-1}$}edge [<-] (h1);
\node[index] (W-2) [left =of W-1] {$w_{t-2}$} edge [<-] (h1);
\node[index] (W+1) [above right =of h1] {$w_{t+1}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\node[index] (W+2) [right =of W+1] {$w_{t+2}$}edge [<-] (h1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to do two more things? Make the `wt` box circle, along with the other square boxes, i.e. I don't need multiple square boxes and just a signle circle would be better.

Comment: @user113156: Do you want to replace the seven square boxes by a single circular box or by seven circular boxes? What radius should it/they have?

Comment: I would like to replace the 7 square boxes as a single circle, I have no preference in regards to the radius, I can modify these later?

Comment: @user113156: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am trying to create this by removing the `w0` and keeping everything else the same. Would I need to use `\node[hidden]`?

Comment: @user113156: I have added another addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As a side note: `hidden` is just the name of the node style that was chosen to draw rectanlges split up into 7 smaller boxes. If you don't want these boxes, don't use `\node[hidden]`.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought it was to create a "hidden" node from which I call/initialise `left = of HiddenNode`, etc.

Comment: @user113156: When I first saw the code, I thought the same, however, you can find the definition of the `hidden` node in: `\tikzset{hidden/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,rectangle split parts=7,draw=black},}`. Generally, you can use `\tikzset{<yourname>/.style=...}` to define a style that you can later use as follows: `\node[<yourname>]...`.

Comment: I wonder which of provided examples is actually answer to (unclear) OP question?